# Prove that $\sup_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) = \max_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I'm reading the proof of Sion's theorem in which the following lemma is implicitly used.

> Let $X,Y$ be nonempty subsets of normed vector spaces and $X$ compact. Consider $g: X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ such that for each $y \in Y, v\in\mathbb R$, the set $\{x \in X \mid g(x,y) \ge v\}$ is closed in $X$. Prove that $$\sup_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) = \max_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y)$$

Could you please verify whether my attempt is fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

---

**My attempt:**

Consider the function $$f:X \to \mathbb R, \quad x \mapsto \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y)$$

For $v \in \mathbb R$, we have $$\begin{aligned} \{x\in X \mid f(x) \ge v\} &= \{x\in X \mid \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) \ge v\}\\ &= \{x\in X \mid \forall y \in Y: g(x,y) \ge v\} \\&= \bigcap_{y\in Y} \{x\in X \mid g(x,y) \ge v\} \end{aligned}$$

Because $\{x\in X \mid g(x,y) \ge v\}$ is closed in $X$, $\{x\in X \mid f(x) \ge v\}$ is closed in $X$. As such, $f$ is upper semi-continuous.

Because an upper semi-continuous function attains maximum on a compact set, $\sup_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y) = \sup_{x\in X} f(x) = \max_{x\in X} f(x) = \max_{x\in X} \inf_{y \in Y} g(x,y)$.