# Prove that $\max_{x \in X} \inf _{y \in Y^{\prime}} g(x, y)<v < \inf _{y \in Y^{\prime} \sup_{x \in X}} g(x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, game-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Good night, I'm reading Sion's Minmax Theorem:

> [image]

and its proof:

> [image]

Could you please confirm if my understanding why $\max_{x \in X} \inf _{y \in Y^{\prime}} g(x, y) < v < \inf _{y \in Y^{\prime} \sup_{x \in X}} g(x, y)$ is correct?

**My attempt:**

1. $\max_{x \in X} \inf _{y \in Y^{\prime}} g(x, y) < v$

It suffices to show that for all $x \in X$, $\inf_{y \in Y^{\prime}} g(x, y)<v$. To prove $\inf_{y \in Y^{\prime}} g(x, y)<v$, it suffices to show that $\exists y \in Y': g(x,y) < v$.

Because $(X_y)_{y \in Y_0}$ is a finite subcover of $X$ and $Y_0 \subseteq Y'$, there is $\bar y \in Y'$ such that $x \in X_{\bar y}$. Then $g(x,\bar y) < v$. This completes the proof.

2. $v < \inf_{y \in Y^{\prime}} \sup_{x \in X} g(x, y)$

It follows from $Y' \subseteq Y$ that $\inf _{y \in Y} \sup _{x \in X} g(x, y) \le \inf _{y \in Y'} \sup _{x \in X} g(x, y)$. On the other hand, $v < \inf _{y \in Y} \sup _{x \in X} g(x, y)$. Hence $v < \inf_{y \in Y^{\prime}} \sup_{x \in X} g(x, y)$.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400764/prove-that-sup-x-in-x-inf-y-in-y-gx-y-max-x-in-x-inf-y-in-y-g or are you asking something different here?

Comment: Hi @Math1000, I actually ask for a different point of the proof.